# unable to print last part from a pointer array of characters

Tags: c

In a c program, I am trying to insert all the words of a two dimensional pointer array of characters  one by one  in another character array using loop and in the process keep printing it. works fine except the last part of each row or one dimensional array is not printed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str[]={
        "We will teach you how to...",
        "Move a mountain",
        "Level a building",
        "Erase the past",
        "Make a million",
        "...all through C!"
     };

     int row=6,col,n=0;

     char str1[20],str2[20],num[n];
     char temp;

     for(int r=0;r<row;)
     {
         for(int c=0;c<strlen(*(str+r));c++)
         {
           temp=*(*(str+r)+c);
           if(temp!=' ')
           {
             num[n]=temp;
             n++;
           }
           else
           {
            num[n]='\0';
            n=0;
            printf("%s ",num);
           }
        }
        r++;
       printf("\n");
       n=0;
   }
}
```

Comment: `temp=*(*(str+r)+c);` is more readable IMHO as `temp = str[r][c];` ... and **why** `EOF`???? (it will **never** be `EOF`, besides `EOF` is an int, `temp` is a char)

Comment: Thank you Sir, i did not know about that. I am just trying to learn to code. I removed that part but left the value of n to be zero as the row value incremented. but still the same problem happening. How can i fix it?

Comment: You're only doing the printing when reaching a space. That's obviously not going to happen at the end of a line, so you need to add printing there as well.

Comment: #interjay thank you for the answer! addedd this part inside the loop, if(c==(strlen(*(str+r))-1))
                {
                        num[n]='\0';
                        n=0;
                        printf("%s ",num);
                }
It solved the problem.

Comment: C array won't expand automatically and you have to allocate enough elements when declaring.